# How to handle application session failure in weblogic cluster and load balancer

Tags: cluster-computing, load-balancing, weblogic12c

I have two managed servers added to a cluster in a weblogic server and a load balancer used to manage traffic to these servers. My Application is deployed to this cluster and accessible from URL of load balancer which is working fine. While monitoring requests serving in these managed servers, I can see it is distributed and serving fine to users. 
If i shutdown 1 managed server, my application get down and page shows network error but it will go to login page if i refresh or reload the page. i can see that the request at that time was redirected to the managed server which is in running state.

How can I avoid this failure?
Also how can i redirect the session to at least bounce back to the login screen without showing the connection failure to the user ?

Comment: your load balancer in front of the cluster must be in charge of handling server failure and redirect http requests to another living server instance

Comment: Load balancer is currently set up in a remote physical server in some other place. So, I need to handle this issue from our end itself. Is it possible to do anything from Weblogic server 12c? I don't have much knowledge about this. But, I've read about http replication and tried the same, however it didn't succeed. (added PersistentStoreType as REPLICATED_IF_CLUSTERED in the weblogic.xml file in my ADF application)